# How to forward all paths that start with a specific location in nginx?

Tags: regex, api, nginx, proxy, location

I want to forward all paths that start with /api/ (/api/*  ??) to port 1000 but the actual configuration either forwards only the paths that contain "/api/" and nothing else after (/api/login is not forwarded)

```
location /api/ {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:1000/;
            }
```

or it doesn't work at all

```
location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:1000/;
            }
```

. The server is cinfigured as fallows:

```
server {
            listen       80;
            keepalive_timeout    70;
            server_name  server_name;

            location / {
                    root /var/www/html;
                    index index.html;
            }
            location /api/ {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:1000/;
            }
            }
```

I would appreciate any help, Thank you!

Comment: If `/api/login` isn't being processed by this location block, there must be another location or rewrite statement that is taking precedence. We would need to see more of your configuration and the relevant entries from your access and error logs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Does this mean that I have to map all api paths in nging and tehere is no method to automatize the redirect all paths which start with /api/?

Comment: No. The locations within your question **will match** any URI that begins with `/api/` **unless** there is another location or rewrite statement somewhere else in your configuration that is overriding it.

Comment: All right, I added now the entire configuration, maybe the error is influenced by the first location "/"?

Comment: That configuration causes an error. Have you looked at the error log or tested it using `nginx -T`?

Comment: I changed now the configuration for "~ ^/api/(.*)$" to "/api/". He matches the path /api right but when I go to /api/ui there occurs: "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." Unfortunately I don't have the nginx command, even after exporting the path variable... is there another method to check the logs?

Answer (score 3):

Note that with:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1000/;
}
```

If there is request `/api/foo`, then your API server will see `/foo`.

If, on the other hand (note there is no trailing slash in `proxy_pass`) you use:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1000;
}
```

Then for the same request, your API server will receive request "as is": `/api/foo`.

So make sure you use the right approach (slash / no slash) which depends on how your API server handles URLs (if it is configured to handle `/api/foo` URLs then you should not use trailing slash in the `proxy_pass`.