# How to rewrite nginx path from "http://domain/api/path" to "http://domain"

Tags: api, nginx, server, proxy, url-rewriting

I'm configuring the nginx to redirect all incoming uris which start with

```
/api
```

to the backend, this means port 1000. The issue is that the frontend path

```
/api/path/
```

becomes the backend

```
/
```

but I need it to stay the same. For example when I navigate to the backend

```
http://domain/api/path
```

I have to actually navigate to

```
http://domain/api/path/api/path
```

. Is there a possibility to rewrite the expression in order to keep the same path? The actual configuration looks like this:

```
location /api/ui {
                    include proxy_params;
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:1000/;
            }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to forward all paths that start with a specific location in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911675/how-to-forward-all-paths-that-start-with-a-specific-location-in-nginx)

Comment: I have already answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911675/how-to-forward-all-paths-that-start-with-a-specific-location-in-nginx/58922449#58922449). This is duplicate actually.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem!